# Pentaho bi-server 6.1 on aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pentaho

I have installed the new Pentaho BI server 6.1 with java 8 on an AWS amazon server.

When I launched `ip:8080/pentaho` I had this error :

> This site can't be reached  "ip" took too long to respond.
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT.

Catalina.out does not show any error.

I am really lost. Your help will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: generally it should work..
have you opened 8080 port in amazon server?

Comment: can you use any alias on the server?

Comment: Thanks ,  the problem was the port 8080

Comment: I am facing another problem now. After doing all the set up for mysql repository in the bi-server. Here is what i got when I restart the server: The following errors were detected
One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
   org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.connection.datasource.dbcp.DynamicallyPooledDatasourceSystemListener

Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.